# Baysian Network, pkg, Gemtc, mtc.nodeplist error

Tags: r, consistency, mcmc

I have been working on a Bayesian network analysis in the "gemtc" package comparing many different treatments, with little back-up from multiple articles. I've installed all of the necessary packages RJAG either. This is my data set called 'Entire':

```
study treatment   diff std.err
1 A   AA         -0.3425 0.1064
2 A   AB         NA           NA
3 B   AA        -0.4943    0.1086
4 B   AB          NA         NA
5 C   ADV       -0.0305      0.0991
6 C   AD          NA           NA
7 D   AA         -0.1054 0.1076
8 D   AB           NA      NA
9 E   AD           0.0392  0.2632
10 E  AB           NA       NA
11 F  ABV           -0.01508    030685
12 F  AB           NA     NA
13 G  K            -0.0325   031179
14 G  AD            NA NA
15 H  L            030488    0.1084
15 H  AB            NA NA
16 I  AD            -0.0408     0.1078
16 I  M             NA NA
17 J  O             -0.0274     0.0967
17 J  AB             NA NA
```

Here is the necessary script:

```
network <- mtc.network(data.re = Entire, description = "Network")
summary(network)
nodesplit<-mtc.nodesplit(network, linearModel='random', n.adapt=10000, n.iter=100000, thin=10)
summary(nodesplit)
```

Once I run the mtc.nodesplit I get the following error:

```
Error in mtc.nodesplit(network, linearModel = "random", n.adapt = 10000,  : 
  There are no comparisons to assess for inconsistency. See https://doi.org/10.1002/jrsm.1167 for how this is determined.
```

I used within the same script long time ago but it worked before. . How can I resolve this error?

I also ran the Monte Carlo simulation and plot of network, these worked without any problems.

Inconcistency test is required to assess for NMA.